# Eclipse Does Not Recognize JRE 8 as Greater Than JRE 5

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I have installed Java 8 on my machine and have started a project with it. However, when I use an `@Override` annotation, the code is underlined in red, and the error `Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater` appears.

I have installed the released Eclipse Java Development Tools Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2), but this only adds support for new features in Java 8, and does not fix the bug with annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your INSTALLED_JRE is pointing to jdk 1.8 in eclipse

```
Preference > java > installed_jre
```

Make sure java > compiler is set to 1.8 in eclipse

```
preference > java > compiler > compiler compliance level
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. Both of these are set to 1.8

Comment: There are also project-specific settings for the source level.

Comment: Then you should not see that message.  Are you sure it is set on the project too?

Comment: @DaveC for project level & workspace level ? if yet hit refresh and rebuild project

Comment: Seconding the _Project->Clean..._ even if all the 1.8 settings are correct in the various UI locations. Had a similar problem today with my 1.8 setup, where a previously-working project flagged a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you can try right click the project name and run Maven/Update Project.

Answer (score 0):

by default 1.4 version will set, so make sure set   preference > java > compiler > compiler compliance level  in eclipse IDE